# How to include a pdf when using dvisvgm

Tags: tikz-pgf, includegraphics, dvisvgm

I'm trying to make SVG versions of my TikZ pictures with the `dvisvgm` driver described in the manual, but I'm stuck on pictures that include PDF images.

Example:

Content of `red_circle.tex`, to make the PDF to be included:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [red,line width=2mm] (0,0) circle [radius=1];
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Content of `picture.tex`:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz,dvisvgm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [line width=4mm] (0,0) -- (1.5,1.5);
    \node [draw,blue!50!white,line width=2mm,opacity=0.5]
          {\includegraphics{red_circle}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The first file is just an example to get something to include in the second file. Here I build `red_circle.pdf` with `pdflatex`.

Now I try to build the SVG from the second file like this:

```
latex picture
dvisvgm picture
```

but the first command fails with `LaTeX Error: File red_circle not found`.

The only way I found to compile this file is by first converting `red_circle.pdf` to EPS. But the result looks awful: the circle is badly rasterized and transparency is lost:

[image: Bad result]

instead of

[image: Expected result]

Is there a way to make such inclusion work?

Edit: as suggested by David I can convert `red_circle.pdf` to SVG or PNG. This works if I write the extension explicitly in the `\includegraphics` call. There are two issues however:

- the node opacity is not applied to the included image
- the image is included by reference to another file: `picture.svg` includes code such as `<image height='83.14932' width='83.14932' xlink:href='red_circle.svg'/>` which is a bit messy and doesn't work in all viewers (for example I cannot post-process the file with `convert` from ImageMagick).

Edit 2: As noted by AlexG I just need to specify `.pdf` in the `\includegraphics` call.

Comment: you could (perhaps) convert the pdf to svg then reference the svg file, the dvisvgm manual says svg png and jpg are supported (so not eps or pdf)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks for the suggestion! It sort of works but is far from optimal (see edit at the bottom of the question).

Comment: If I append `.pdf` I get the expected result.

Comment: Hehe how could I miss that :) thanks!

Comment: Should this question be deleted? I guess it can still be useful for people who make the same mistake...

Comment: Actually, adding the file extension should not be necessary, but for some reason is. Other people might stumble over this again. Therefore, I'd keep the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file extension `.pdf`is missing in the list of extensions

```
\def\Gin@extensions{.svg,.eps,.png,.jpg,.jpeg}
```

in the `graphic[sx]` driver file `dvisvgm.def`.

Also, the extension list from `dvisvgm.def` gets overwritten with an outdated setting by other driver packages in the loading sequence. Therefore, `svg`, `png`, `jpeg` are forgotten as well.

To re-enable support for those graphics formats, re-read `dvisvgm.def` in the preamble and manually add `.pdf`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,dvisvgm]{standalone}

\makeatletter
\input{dvisvgm.def}
\makeatother

\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [line width=4mm] (0,0) -- (1.5,1.5);
    \node [draw,blue!50!white,line width=2mm,opacity=0.5]
          {\includegraphics{red_circle}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is a bug and should be reported to the LaTeX team.

Comment: These fixes don't seem to work on my system (TeX Live 2020): either fixing `dvisvgm.def` or adding the line in the preamble, I still get `LaTeX Error: File red_circle not found`. Note that without explicit extension it also fails to find SVG, PNG and JPEG files. It seems only EPS is found by default.

Comment: Fixing `dvisvgm.def`  alone does not seem to be enough, as `\Gin@extensions` gets overwritten by other driver packages. However, `\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf}` added to the preamble (just before `\begin{document}`) gets it right. I tested this with TL20 and TL21.

Comment: Ah sorry the preamble line is working indeed. But if the correct fix was to change `\Gin@extensions`, it should work already for PNG, JPEG and SVG files. So there must be another issue too (or does it work for you when you include e.g. a PNG without explicit extension?)

Comment: As I said, `\Gin@extensions` gets overwritten with an outdated list by other pkgs. See edited answer.

Comment: I see, thanks for looking into the details.